# Does Slick have a way of taking a dynamic query size?

Tags: dynamic, slick

I'm trying to make a query with slick, where one of the parameters is the number of elements the query returns (normally you achieve this by passing the parameter to '.take').  However, I want this parameter to be optional (looking for a command like .maybeFilter, but for .take), and I've been looking all over but can't seem to find it.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dynamic query filter 
[slick-doc](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/queries.html)

1.first way(all dynamic filter are 'and')

```
def selectByHotelIdAndStartTimeAndEndTimeAndPerpageAndOffset(
      hotelId: Option[String],
      caseTimeFilter: Option[CaseTimeFilter[Timestamp]],
      perPage: Int,
      offset: Int
  ): Future[Seq[GoodsOrderMstinfoTRow]] =
    db.run(
      tableQ
        .filter { goodsOrderMstinfoT: GoodsOrderMstinfoT =>
          List(
            hotelId.map(goodsOrderMstinfoT.hotelid === _),
            caseTimeFilter.map(t => goodsOrderMstinfoT.createTime between (t.start, t.end))
          ).collect({ case Some(repBoolean) => repBoolean })
            .reduceLeftOption(_ && _)
            .getOrElse(true: Rep[Boolean])
        }
        .drop(offset)
        .take(perPage)
        .sortBy(_.gomtId.desc)
        .result
    )
```

2.second way

```
def selectCountByHotelIdAndStartTimeAndEndTime(
      optionHotelId: Option[String],
      rmiSerialno: Option[String],
      caseTimeFilter: Option[CaseTimeFilter[Timestamp]]
  ): Future[Int] =
    db.run(
      tableQ
        .filter { RoomReviewT: RoomReviewT =>
          optionHotelId match {
            case Some(hotelid) => RoomReviewT.hotelid === hotelid
            case None          => true: Rep[Boolean]
          }
        }
        .filter { RoomReviewT: RoomReviewT =>
          rmiSerialno match {
            case Some(rmiSerialNo) => RoomReviewT.rmiSerialno === rmiSerialNo
            case None              => true: Rep[Boolean]
          }
        }
        .filter { RoomReviewT: RoomReviewT =>
          caseTimeFilter match {
            case Some(timeFilter) =>
              RoomReviewT.createTime between (timeFilter.start, timeFilter.end)
            case None => true: Rep[Boolean]
          }
        }
        .length
        .result
    )
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest capturing the main query you want to run, and then applying the `take` using regular `Option` methods. Something like:

```
def query(taking: Option[Int]) = {
  val baseQuery = table.filter(...).map(...)
  taking.map(size => baseQuery.take(size)) getOrElse baseQuery
}
```

If you're doing that a lot, it may make sense to wrap the behaviour into its own class like the [MaybeFilter](https://gist.github.com/studiodev/5c6471cb1d823914ee28).